# Как из long-polling канала прочитать только последнее сообщение?

Tags: php, javascript, nginx, long-poll

При реализации простейшего обмена сообщениями через long-polling с помощью nginx возникла проблема: в XMLHttpRequest.responseText приходят все сообщения, которые были отправлены в этот канал, а не одно. Не думаю, что так и должно быть.

Получение сообщений (js):

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/sub/' + subID, true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = xhr.onload = function () {
if (xhr.status == 200) {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
}
```

Отсюда вопрос: проблема в конфигурации модуля nginx, или в чем-то еще?
Отправка сообщения:

```
$channel_id = '1';
$msg = array('text' => 'a');

$ch = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/pub?id='.$channel_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($msg));
if (curl_exec($ch)) 
  echo 'sended '.json_encode($msg);
else 
  echo 'fail';
curl_close($ch);
```

NGINX:

```
location / {
            location ~ /sub/(.*) {
                # activate subscriber (streaming) mode for this location
                push_stream_subscriber;

                # positional channel path
                push_stream_channels_path                 $1;
                push_stream_longpolling_connection_ttl    30s;
                push_stream_last_received_message_time    $arg_time; 
                push_stream_last_received_message_tag     $arg_tag;
            }
            location /pub {
               # activate publisher (admin) mode for this location
               push_stream_publisher admin; 
                # query string based channel id
                push_stream_channels_path               $arg_id;
            }
            location /channels-stats {
                # activate channels statistics mode for this location
                push_stream_channels_statistics;

                # query string based channel id
                push_stream_channels_path               $arg_id;
            }
```

UPD: изменил на:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/sub/' + subID, true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = xhr.onload = function () {
    alert(xhr.readyState);
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
if (xhr.status === 200) {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
}
}
```

теперь в console не пишется ничего, а alert показывает, что xhr.readyState при получении сообщения бывает только 2, а потом 3. до 4 не доходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, кроме `xhr.status === 200` нужно проверить еще `xhr.readyState === 4`, чтобы обработать responseText, когда сообщение отправлено полностью. См. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: изменил на:
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/sub/' + subID, true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = xhr.onload = function () {
 alert(xhr.readyState);
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
if (xhr.status === 200) {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
}
}

теперь в console не пишется ничего, а alert показывает, что xhr.readyState при получении сообщения бывает только 2, а потом 3. до 4 не доходит

Comment: @fLipE у вас сервер не отправляет признак конца ответа, а должен. Не знаю, как это в PHP, в node.js это делается вызовом метода `end` у объекта `response`. Клиент считает, что данные с сервера еще будут приходить. Полностью прочитать ответ сервера вы сможете только когда readyState будет равен 4.

Comment: спасибо) попробую что-нибудь придумать)